# creating cascaded elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got the following assignment:

> create a div with a button dynamically, and this in turn they should create another (div with button), so on.

Yet the following code does not work:

```
<div id="M-0">
    <div id="M-0C"></div>
    <input id="add_container" name="add_container" class="cua" type="button" value="Addition Container"  >
</div>
```

and the Jquery Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cua").live("click", function(e){
        var father = $(this).parent();          
        var id_new=father.attr('id')+'.M-';
        var number=0;
        while( $('#'+id_new+number).length ){
            number=number+1;
        }
        id_new=id_new+number;
        alert('here '+id_new);
        $('#'+father.attr('id')+'C').append('<div id="'+id_new+'"><div id="'+id_new+'C"></div><input id="add_container" name="add_container" class="cua" type="button" value="Addition Container" ></div>');
    });
});
```

A click on the first button works, but the next click on the newly created button is not working.

Comment: So, why not? Do you get the alert with the new id? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: At the second click `$('#'+father.attr('id')+'C')` does not exist because `father` is `#M-0C`, so it tries to look for `#M-0CC`.

Comment: The console i working, but i prefer alert because it stoped the execution

Comment: I check every Id's, all is right. because the struture is <div id='M-0'><div id='M-0C'></div><input type='button'></div> and the new strucutre is inserted in "M-0C", (the new structure have the same structure that original structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `on()`..

```
$(document).on('click','.cua',function(e){
   var father = $(this).parent();          
    var id_new=father.attr('id')+'.M-';
    var number=0;
   .....

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/H2pgT/)

Comment: @musa.. correct... i don't know what was i thinkinh then... i think i need a coffee now.. anyways thanks.. :)...updated...using on delegated event for the created element should work...

Answer (score 0):

**Markup**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="button"><button>Add More</button></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $parent = $('#parent');
var $button = $parent.find('.button');

$(document).on('click', '.button button', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    $parent.append($button.clone());

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcCA8/1/)